# How to generate model and table dynamically in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to DJango. I have an requirement to create a table at runtime, I mean whenever a new user signup on my application,
a new table should be created with that user's name, so table should be created with out migration command,
My DB is mysql,

```
attrs = {
    'name': models.CharField(max_length=32),
    '__module__': 'myapp.models'
}
dynamic_username="riswan"
user_model = type(dynamic_username, (models.Model,), attrs)
```

how to implement this ? Please help

Comment: Normally you do *not* create a new table, but you make one table with a `ForeignKey` to the user to keep track of what the records are "owned" by that user.

Comment: I know that, but this is a special case, its a  shopping cart application for every seller has large number of orders, So I decided to do that way

Comment: but a `ForeignKey` adds an index making accessing quite fast. In case there are performance issues, you should use *sharding*, but defining an extra table per customer does not make much sense. But a table is a *conceptual* layer, whereas the physical layer is specified through shards, etc.

Comment: Do you plan on using the ORM to query those user tables? Out of curiosity how many orders is each seller going to have? Assuming the seller is the user in this case? Are you using https://pypi.org/project/django-dynamic-model/ ?